# Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy. Prove that $\{|x_n-y_n|\}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not entire sure how to proceed on this question. I believe I am supposed to use a triangle inequality with epsilons and $m$, $n \geq N$ to get $N_1$ and $N_2$ before setting it to $\max\{N_1, N_2\}$. The absolute value in the question is making this tricky for me. I'm wondering how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must show that for $m,n\geq N$ we have:
$$
||x_m-y_m|-|x_n-y_n||\leq\varepsilon
$$
from the triangle inequality applied twice in two different versions we know that:
$$
\begin{align}
||x_m-y_m|-|x_n-y_n||
&\leq|x_m-y_m+x_n-y_n|\\
&\leq|x_m-x_n|+|y_m-y_n|
\end{align}
$$
and the last two terms can be made as small as you like by the assumption of $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ both being Cauchy. The two triangle inequalities used here are:

1. $||x|-|y||\leq|x-y|$
2. $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$

Comment: Little confused, did your signs change in xm and xn on the second step of the inequality? Not sure why it isn't |xn-xm| +|yn-ym| for the last step instead.

Comment: @Anon Note that $|y_n-y_m|=|y_m-y_n|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You have to prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such 
if $n,m > N$ then $|x_n -y_n -x_m + y_m| < \epsilon$

Using triangle inequality we get

$$|(x_n -x_m)+(y_m-y_n)|\leq |x_n - x_m| + |y_n -y_m| $$

Since $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy you can set $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and the proof is almost finished

**Edit:**

As said in the comments I forgot you want $\{|x_ -y_n|\}$ not $\{x_n -y_n\}$ as I tohught. Then all you need is the previous step shown in the answer by @String

Comment: I believe you want $||x_n-y_n|-|x_m-y_m||$, so you cannot immediately rearrange to $||x_n-x_m|+|y_n-y_m||$.